# Unity - Perlin noise Octaves

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, perlin-noise

I'am trying to setup simple Terrain Generator in unity following tutorial, so far it works as intended, but i wanted to do more "natural" look and found out that i need to do Octaves or MultiLevel noise.

Everything i found online regarding Multilevel Perlin noise, was not understandable for me or used completly different methode.

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
public class Mesh_Generator : MonoBehaviour
{

    #region Variables
    Mesh mesh;

    Vector3[] vertices;
    //Vector2[] Uvs;
    Color[] colors;
    int[] triangles;

    [Range(1, 9999)]
    public int xSize = 100;
    [Range(1, 9999)]
    public int zSize = 100;

    public Gradient gradient;

    public float MinHeight = 0;
    public float MaxHeight = 0;

    public bool Reset_Min_Max;
    #endregion
    #region Octaves
    [Range(1, 6)]
    public int Octaves = 6;
    public int Scale = 50;

    public float offsetX = 0f;
    public float offsetY = 0f;

    public float Frequency_01 = 5f;
    public float FreqAmp_01 = 3f;

    public float Frequency_02 = 6f;
    public float FreqAmp_02 = 2.5f;

    public float Frequency_03 = 3f;
    public float FreqAmp_03 = 1.5f;

    public float Frequency_04 = 2.5f;
    public float FreqAmp_04 = 1f;

    public float Frequency_05 = 2f;
    public float FreqAmp_05 = .7f;

    public float Frequency_06 = 1f;
    public float FreqAmp_06 = .5f;
    #endregion
    #region Start
    void Start()
    {
        mesh = new Mesh();
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;

        offsetX = Random.Range(0f, 99999f);
        offsetY = Random.Range(0f, 99999f);
    }
    #endregion
void ResetMinMax()
{
    MinHeight = 0f;
    MaxHeight = 0f;
        Reset_Min_Max = false;
}
#region Update
private void Update()
    {
        if (Reset_Min_Max)
            ResetMinMax();

        CreateShape();
        UpdateMesh();
    }
    #endregion
    #region CreateShape
    void CreateShape()
    {
        #region Vertices
        vertices = new Vector3[(xSize + 1) * (zSize + 1)];

        for (int i = 0, z = 0; z <= zSize; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= xSize; x++)
            {
                float y = Calculate(x, z);
                vertices[i] = new Vector3(x, y, z);

                if (y > MaxHeight)
                    MaxHeight = y;
                if (y < MinHeight)
                    MinHeight = y;

                i++;
            }
        }

        int vert = 0;
        int tris = 0;
        #endregion
        #region Triangles
        triangles = new int[xSize * zSize * 6];

        for (int z = 0; z < zSize; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < xSize; x++)
            {
                triangles[tris + 0] = vert + 0;
                triangles[tris + 1] = vert + xSize + 1;
                triangles[tris + 2] = vert + 1;
                triangles[tris + 3] = vert + 1;
                triangles[tris + 4] = vert + xSize + 1;
                triangles[tris + 5] = vert + xSize + 2;

                vert++;
                tris += 6;
            }
            vert++;
        }
        #endregion
        #region Gradient Color
        colors = new Color[vertices.Length];
        for (int i = 0, z = 0; z <= zSize; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= xSize; x++)
            {
                float Height = Mathf.InverseLerp(MinHeight, MaxHeight, vertices[i].y);
                colors[i] = gradient.Evaluate(Height);
                i++;
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region UVs
        /*
         Uvs = new Vector2[vertices.Length];
         for (int i = 0, z = 0; z <= zSize; z++)
         {
             for (int x = 0; x <= xSize; x++)
             {
                 Uvs[i] = new Vector2((float)x / xSize, (float)z / zSize);
                 i++;
             }
         }
         */
        #endregion
    }
    #endregion
    #region Octaves Calculation
    float Calculate(float x, float z)
    {
        float[] octaveFrequencies = new float[] { Frequency_01, Frequency_02, Frequency_03, Frequency_04, Frequency_05, Frequency_06 };
        float[] octaveAmplitudes = new float[] { FreqAmp_01, FreqAmp_02, FreqAmp_03, FreqAmp_04, FreqAmp_05, FreqAmp_06 };
        float y = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < Octaves; i++)
        {
            y += octaveAmplitudes[i] * Mathf.PerlinNoise(
                     octaveFrequencies[i] * x + offsetX * Scale,
                     octaveFrequencies[i] * z + offsetY * Scale) ;

        }

        return y;
    }
    #endregion
    #region UpdateMesh
    void UpdateMesh()
    {
        mesh.Clear();

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        mesh.colors = colors;
        //mesh.uv = Uvs;

        mesh.RecalculateNormals();

    }
    #endregion
    #region  Gizmos
    /* 
     private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (vertices == null)
            return;

        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++){
            Gizmos.DrawSphere(vertices[i], .1f);
        }           
    }
    */
    #endregion
}
```

In link below is my current result and result which i'am trying to achieve.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFMLQ.jpg

is it possible to achieve such result using this method ? 
if so would be possible to show script example ?

Thank you a lot.

*updated code again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

multi level, or multi octave perlin is just few iterations of  standard perlin added together.
An example code could look like this:

```
float[] octaveFrequencies=new float() {1,1.5f,2,2.5f} ;
float[] octaveAmplitudes=new float() {1,0.9f,0.7f,0.f} ;
float y=0;
for(int i=0;i<octaveFrequencies.Length;i++)
 y += octaveAmplitudes[i]* Mathf.PerlinNoise(
      octaveFrequencies[i]*x + .3f, 
      octaveFrequencies[i]* z + .3f) * 2f ;
```

The numbers you put into arrays will decide the final shape of the noise. Values from the frequencies array are multiplied by your input, values from the amplitudes array are multiplied by the resulting perlin at that layer.

Comment: Thank you this cleared it atleast little bit for me but i think i still doing something wrong as this feels still "artificial" link: https://imgur.com/a/ZvQJ7Ut

i retrieving "Y" from this: 

    float Calculate(float x, float z) where is your piece of code.

Comment: looks roughly like perlin at this frequency, for octaves to show nicely your resolution (in this case vertex count) should be a bit higher (or your base frequency lower), it looks like higher order perlin gets aliased out

Comment: tried to increase number of vertexes this is 512x 256 and it will completly break Graphic :/ and still looks flat tho, i updated code once more in main question.
https://imgur.com/a/NRkXVPl

Comment: Well i semi-achieved what i was looking for but without your code i would not achieve that i just used huge values and thats why it didnt work correctly, issue of not being able to use more the 256x256 vertex still persist tho.

addig valleys / rivers will be easy now as i understand it much more clearly which i thank you a lot :) 

https://imgur.com/a/29jusDe

Comment: Why do you add it together ? wouldn't this cause the noise to exceed the range of 0 and 1 ?